# sql unique and join

Tags: sql

This is a lovely little bit of SQL which I can't write. :)

what I need to do is this;

select the latest value from the table (CreatedOn), for each user, for a specific StatID. I need to then join the usertable (ssUSER) and select the u.username and I also need to join the detailstatid from the table. I.e. I just need the latest result from this table for each user and then do a join on the user and detailstatid.

```
SELECT TOP 1000
   [DetailStatUserLogID]
  ,[UserID]
  ,[DetailStatID]
  ,[OverviewID]
  ,[Count]
  ,[StatPercent]
  ,[SpecificDate]
  ,[CreatedOn]
  ,[ModifiedOn]
  ,[Note]
  ,[LoggedDate]
  ,[OverViewGUID]
FROM [StartStop].[dbo].[DetailStatUserLog]
```

```
SELECT TOP 1000
   [DetailStatID]
  ,[DetailStatGUID]
  ,[NameOfStat]
  ,[DetailOfStat]
  ,[CreatedByType]
  ,[DataType]
  ,[CreatedByGUID]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[ModifiedOn]
  ,[CreatedOn]
  ,[OverviewID]
FROM [StartStop].[dbo].[DetailStat]
```

```
SELECT TOP 1000
   [UserID]
  ,[EmailAddress]
  ,[Authenticated]
  ,[UserName]
FROM [StartStop].[dbo].[ssUsers]
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to give. :)

Comment: Could you please post your table structures or create a fiddle with the tables added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select /* entered desired fields here */
from (select l.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by [UserID], [DetailStatID]
                                order by [CreatedOn] desc) rn
      from DetailStatUserLog l) ll
join ssUsers u on ll.[UserId] = u.[UserId]
Join DetailStat s on ll.[DetailStatId] = s.[DetailStatId]
where ll.rn=1
```

Comment: @philbird: Compared with correlated sub-queries, it should be significantly more efficient - analytical functions are relatively expensive in terms of processing, but normally much less so than multiple table accesses.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm writing a stats application so I really should have a better understanding of this. :) I'll read around.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do want you want. It is hard to test without your DDL or data.

```
Select u.UserName,
       ds.DetailedStat,
       dsl.CreatedOn,
       dsl.DetailStatId,
       dsl.UserId

From 
(
Select d.UserId, d.DetailStatId, Max(d.CreatedOn) as [CreatedOn]
From DetailStatUserLog d
Where d.CreatedOn = (Select Max(CreatedON)
                   From DetailStatUserLog
                   Where UserID = d.UserId
                   And DetailStatId = d.DetailStatId
                   )
Group By d.UserId, d.DetailStatId

)dsl
Join ssUsers u on dsl.UserId = u.UserId
Join detailstat ds on dsl.DetailStatId = ds.DetailStatId
```

Comment: Thanks for having a pop at it Barry. :) It tells me;An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: @philbird: I did miss out a `From` clause which I have added. What line is that as it works fine for me. Have you added something in?